# How to programmatically determine if user projecting screen in Skype or Lync

Tags: c#, .net, skype, lync-2013

is there an API to check if user currently sharing the screen in Skype or Lync? I want to suppress some actions during screen sharing sessions. 
It is Windows Forms application.